# How do I convert following code to streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have a list how can I convert it to a Map in which I can have keys with minimum value as key value pair. I want to convert this code to streams.

```
Map<Long, Date> formToDate = new HashMap<>();
    for(FormInstance formInstance : formInstances) {
        if(formToDate.get(formInstance.getForm().getId()) == null) {
            formToDate.put(formInstance.getForm().getId(), formInstance.getCreatedDate());
        }
        else{
            Date prevDate = formToDate.get(formInstance.getForm().getId());
            Date thisDate = formInstance.getCreatedDate();
            formToDate.put(formInstance.getForm().getId(), prevDate.before(thisDate) ? prevDate : thisDate);
        }
    }
```

to something like this:

```
Map<Long, List<Date>> formToDate = formInstances.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(formInstance -> formInstance.getForm().getId(),
                            Collectors.mapping(FormInstance::getCreatedDate, Collectors.toList())));
```

But instead of returning list all I want to have the smallest date.

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and [edit] your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Perhaps you'd be best to write your own `Collector` here.

Comment: or maybe use the `Collectors.minBy` collector... but the code given above is not just returning the smallest date!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `Collector::toMap` implementation which provides a merge function. This can be used to determine the smallest date from two different entries with same id like:

```
Map<Long, Date> minimum = formInstances.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        fi -> fi.getForm().getId(), 
        FormInstance::getCreatedDate, 
        (date, date2) -> date.before(date2) ? date : date2
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Flown's answer is nice if you really want to use streams, but often it is possible to do without while still taking advantage of newer Java features. I have seen many cases (myself included) in which streams were used for the sake of using streams instead of taking a simpler, more direct approach.

If you already have a list and want to avoid creating a stream, you can use the new `Map.merge()` method:

```
Map<Long, Date> minimum = new HashMap<>();
forms.forEach(form -> minimum.merge(form.getForm().getId(),
                                    form.getCreatedDate(),
                                    (date, date2) -> date.before(date2) ? date : date2));
```

Aside from `merge`, `Map` has many methods that can make things like this easier: `computeIfAbsent`, `getOrDefault`, or even the "old" `containsKey` method can make code a lot more readable by replacing common boilerplate snippets, like the one you used:

`if (map.get(key) == null) { add } else { test and put }`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `Collectors.groupingBy` in combination of `Collectors.mapping` and `Collectors.minBy`:

```
Map<Long, Optional<Date>> formToDate =
    formInstances.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(fi -> fi.getForm().getId(),
                                                Collectors.mapping(FormInstance::getCreatedDate,
                                                                   Collectors.minBy(Date::compareTo))));
```